# How To Ensure Correct Extension Method Resolution

Tags: c#, extension-methods, overload-resolution

I'm seeing some unexpected behavior in my extension method resolution, and I'm attempting to figure out why.  I've read [Eric Lippert's Closer is Better](https://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/) article and I'm still confused.

First the call site:

```
// Assembly: DLaB.Xrm.2016.Tests
using DLaB.Xrm.Entities;
using DLaB.Xrm.Test;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;

namespace DLaB.Xrm.Tests 

    public class TrialClass{
    {
        public void Delete(){
            IOrganziationService service = GetService();
            Id<Contact> id = GetId();
            service.Delete(id);  // Call Site in Question
        }
    } 
}
```

IOrganizationService Defines a delete method with this signature:

```
// Assembly: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk
void Delete(string entityName, Guid id);
```

I have defined Extension method overloads on the IOrganziationService in two different namespaces, in two different assemblies:

```
//Assembly: DLaB.Xrm.2016
//Namespace DLaB.Xrm
public static void Delete(this IOrganizationService service, Entity entity) { ... }
public static void Delete(this IOrganizationService service, EntityReference entity) { ... }


//Assembly: DLaB.Xrm.Test.2016
//Namespace DLaB.Xrm.Test
public static void Delete(this IOrganizationService service, Id id) { ... }
public static void Delete<T>(this IOrganizationService service, Id<T> entity) where T : Entity { ... }
```

I have also defined implicit operators for the Id Class that convert it to an `Entity` or an `EntityReference`

> The Call Site `service.Delete(id)` shows a compiler error:
>   Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties: 'Extensions.Delete(IOrganizationService, Entity)' and
>   'Extensions.Delete(IOrganizationService, EntityReference)'

Which I understand from my implicit operators I've defined.  What I'm not understanding, is why the `DLaB.Xrm` namespace is closer than the `DLaB.Xrm.Test` namespace, even though I do not have a using directive for it.

Answer (score 2):

There are 6 rules of closeness defined in Eric's Blog:

1. A method first declared in a derived class is closer than a method first declared in a base class.
2. A method in a nested class is closer than a method in a containing class.
3. Any method of the receiving type is closer than any extension method.
4. An extension method found in a class in a nested namespace is closer than an extension method found in a class in an outer namespace.
5. An extension method found in a class in the current namespace is closer than an extension method found in a class in a namespace mentioned by a using directive.
6. An extension method found in a class in a namespace mentioned in a using directive where the directive is in a nested namespace is closer than an extension method found in a class in a namespace mentioned in a using directive where the directive is in an outer namespace.

The first 3 do not apply since there is no applicable method for an interface.
The 4th is the key.  DLaB.Xrm is in a nested namespace, even though its in a different assembly.  I had falsely believed that you had to list the using directive of the extension method in order to be able to access it from another class.  I now know that extension methods in nested namespaces are automatically available.

Changing `namespace DLaB.Xrm.Tests` to `namespace NotNested.DLaB.Xrm.Tests` eliminates all the rules of closeness, and the ambiguous call is resolved by normal signature overload resolutions rules.  The actual fix I used was just to make the Delete call generic, which eliminates the two implicit conversion overloads from contention, and allows the call to be resolved to my preferred method.